# Need help on code.org, AppLab in particular

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am trying to create a bunny on AppLab on code.org. Unfortunately, I thought I was using AppLab but I was using GameLab instead. I tried to copy and paste the code onto AppLab but it didn't work as I don't have the same tools as on GameLab. I was wondering if there was anyway of altering the code but the display still remains the same. On AppLab, I can only use these toolbars: Turtle, Math, Controls, Functions. For Controls, I can only use this function : for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

}
 All code and links are down below.

```
//GameLab Code to 

var eyeSize = 70;
var teethlength = 5;

var rabbitSize = 60;


ellipse(153, 66, rabbitSize, rabbitSize*2);  // left ear
ellipse(243, 66, rabbitSize, rabbitSize*2);  // right ear

noStroke();
fill(235, 171, 215);


fill(252, 252, 252);
noStroke();
ellipse( 129, 325, rabbitSize - 22, rabbitSize - 22); // tail

stroke(10, 9, 9);
fill(255, 255, 255);
ellipse( 226, 346, rabbitSize -3, rabbitSize + 1); // back left leg
ellipse( 170, 346, rabbitSize -3, rabbitSize + 1); // back right leg

fill(252, 252, 252);
stroke(59, 56, 56);
ellipse( 198, 276, rabbitSize + 95, rabbitSize + 130); // body
ellipse(200, 153, rabbitSize + 90, rabbitSize + 90); // face

fill(255, 253, 250);
ellipse(170, 150, rabbitSize - 15, rabbitSize - 15); // left eye
ellipse(230, 150, rabbitSize - 15, rabbitSize - 15); // right eye

noStroke();
fill(5, 7, 8);
ellipse( 230, 154, rabbitSize - 29, rabbitSize - 25);
ellipse( 171, 154, rabbitSize - 29, rabbitSize - 25); // retina

fill(13, 10, 13);
ellipse( 230, 159, rabbitSize - 44, rabbitSize - 44); // right eyeball

fill(3, 1, 3);
ellipse( 171, 159, rabbitSize - 44, rabbitSize - 44); // left eyeball

stroke(158, 74, 158);
fill(235, 146, 208);
triangle( rabbitSize + 143, rabbitSize + 127, rabbitSize + 156, rabbitSize + 115, rabbitSize + 129, rabbitSize + 115); // nose

stroke(5, 5, 5);
line(175, 192, 230, 191); // mouth

fill(255, 255, 255);
rect(188, 191, 15, teethlength);  // left tooth
rect(203, 191, 15, teethlength);  // right tooth

fill(255, 252, 254);
ellipse( 168, 275, 47, 75); // left paw
ellipse( 230, 275, 47, 75); // right paw

line( 239, 309, 239, 297); 
line( 230, 312, 230, 301);
line( 220, 309, 220, 297); // right paw lines

line( 159, 309, 159, 297);
line( 177, 309, 177, 297);
line( 168, 312, 168, 301); // left paw lines

stroke(10, 9, 9);
fill(252, 252, 252);
ellipse( 227, 354, 48, 69); // left leg
ellipse( 170, 354, 48, 69); // right leg

fill(240, 175, 221);
noStroke();
ellipse( 158, 339, 12, 13);
ellipse( 171, 331, 12, 13);
ellipse( 183, 339, 12, 13);
ellipse( 171, 364, 28, 37);
ellipse( 171, 357, 32, 24); // left leg-paw

fill(242, 169, 220);
noStroke();
ellipse( 215, 339, 12, 13);
ellipse( 227, 331, 12, 13);
ellipse( 239, 339, 12, 13);
ellipse( 227, 364, 28, 37);
ellipse( 227, 357, 32, 24); // right leg-paw

//Links
https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/
https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the functions can be converted to create a similar output, but you'll have to come up with a different approach for the nose.

Here's a link to the semi-converted code:

https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/0LihHlb_eRn_NdJ_HBcr4NQoqUZjuXSfcnddyBccJ5c/view

Comment: Also, note that the World/screen size is different.